# Can't hide Internet Explorer window using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer, winapi, hide

I'm trying to hide Internet Explorer windows using PowerShell and have tried different approaches but no luck. I've found this code at https://superuser.com/questions/1079133/run-a-windows-application-without-displaying-its-gui, This only works for Notepad. I need help to make this code work for IE i.e an internet explorer window is opened with page Google. I want to hide this window using below code.

```
$definition = @"    
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

      public static void Show(string wClass, string wName)
      {
         IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(wClass, wName);
         if ((int)hwnd > 0)
            ShowWindow(hwnd, 1);
      }

      public static void Hide(string wClass, string wName)
      {
         IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(wClass, wName);
         if ((int)hwnd > 0)
            ShowWindow(hwnd, 0);
      }
"@

add-type -MemberDefinition $definition -Namespace my -Name WinApi

[my.WinApi]::Hide('Internet Explorer', 'Google - Internet Explorer')
```

This code doesn't work to hide internet explorer window.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, possibly? What problem are you solving?

Comment: I want to hide a specific ie window in powershell script during a time interval.

Comment: Why do you want to hide a specific IE window in a PowerShell script?

Comment: This is how you *properly* enumerate IE browser windows: [A big little program: Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 1: Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130610-00/?p=4133).

Comment: It's called a 'browser' for a reason, if you cannot browse it, you shouldn't be using it. I agree with the previous comments. First of all we need to know the specific scenario you're trying to achieve, what exactly your Windows title is, what precisely happens when you run the code, _(that requires your debugging information)_, and what you've tried yourself to fix the issue, before asking others to assist you. Currently it looks as if you've just copied some code, changed two strings, and done absolutely nothing else. Please improve your question, by editing it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that it works when replace 'Internet Explorer' with 'IEFrame'.

it worked with below line

```
[my.WinApi]::Hide("IEFrame", 'Google - Internet Explorer')
```

Comment: You still haven't explained _why_ you need to do it.

Comment: Ditto to what the others are saying ... and are you saying a specific IE/Edge browser tab or you have multiple instances of IE/Edge running potentially with multiple tabs?

Comment: I need this in a project I'm working on. It was about closing IE particular window and this code solved my problem. Even it works for multiple IE instances and also hide IE instance with this specific window when IE running multiple tabs. Thanks everyone.